# Radix 4 reordering function

Tags: c

I have a bit reordering function for a radix 4 algorithm which takes around 600 000 cycles to do its job for 4096 elements of floats (real and imaginary parts):

```
void bit_r4_reorder(float* x, float* y, int N)// N = 4096
{
  int bits = 0;
  int i, j, k;
  float tempr, tempi;

  for (i = 0; i < MAXPOW; i++)//MAXPOW = 24
      if (pow_2[i] == N)
          bits = i;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
      j = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < bits; k += 2)
      {
         if (i & pow_2[k])     j += pow_2[bits - k - 2];
         if (i & pow_2[k + 1]) j += pow_2[bits - k - 1];
      }

  if (j > i)
  {
    tempr = x[i];
    tempi = y[i];
    x[i] = x[j];
    y[i] = y[j];
    x[j] = tempr;
    y[j] = tempi;
  }
 }
}
```

I've counted the cycles for the different parts of this function and it turns to be (maybe pretty obvious) that the last `for()` loop containing the swap part is what takes the most part of cycles.

Can you look at this code and give me some hints or suggestion on how I can optimize the code (if it is even possible)?

Comment: Is `N` always going to be 4096?

Comment: nope, it can be 1024, 4096, 16k ...

Comment: This reordering doesn't look like radix-4.

Comment: @vnp: yes it is its working perfectly and I have the same results as FFTW

Comment: what is `pow_2()` and `MAXPOW`?

Comment: the 6 statements at the end of the function seem to be setting and discarding several CPU registers.  Suggest performing all the `x[]` operations then all the `y[]` operations  as this would avoid several register reloads.  It would also allow the use of a single `tempr` instead of both `tempr` and `tempi`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: in the posted code, the calculated value in `bits` could be quite small.  Then a expression like: `j += pow_2[bits - k - 2];` would result in negative offsets into the array `pow_2[]`  In general, that would be undefined behavior and could lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, my apologies. I completely misread your code.

Ultimately the goal is to reverse bit pairs. The task is very similar to [reversing the bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746171/best-algorithm-for-bit-reversal-from-msb-lsb-to-lsb-msb-in-c) (this discussion is really inspiring), and the approach should be along the same lines.

For example, the first solution can be adopted along the lines of (sorry for sloppy coding):

```
unsigned int radix4_reverse(unsigned int index)
{
    x = (((x & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((x & 0x33333333) << 2));
    x = (((x & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((x & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
    x = (((x & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
    x = (x >> 16) | (x << 16));
    return x >> (32 - bits);
}
```

(notice that the `0xaaaaaaaa`/`0x55555555` line is omitted for it will swap bits within a pair).

Regarding your code,

- `if`s inside the loop are serious performance killers
- `1 << k` is preferable to `pow_2[k]`. The compiler has better chances to optimize sequential shifts than sequential memory fetches. Besides, it relaxes the memory consumption.
- You should operate on bit pairs (e.g. `i & (0x03 << k)` rather than individual bits.
- `|` is cleaner than `+` (IMnsHO).
- I recommend to pass `bits` instead of `N`.